# Can first 7 invariant Hu's moments be extended to 3D?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, medical

I was reading [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-23626-6_26), and in there (3rd page, 18th line from the bottom) the authors have mentioned:

"*we calculate ... the first 7 invariant Hu moments over the intensity values of voxels within the candidate mask.*" (A candidate mask is a 3d mask for a particular lung nodule/false positive candidate in a CT image.)

Everyone around me is saying the Hu's moments are only defined for 2D images. A quick search through literature seems to back them up. So, can anyone guess what the authors are probably doing here? (or Hu's moments can actually be extended to 3D?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hu moments are a combination of the basic geometric moments ([see here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.70.1345)), which can be computed in N-dimensions. Consequently, the Hu moments can be computed for N dimensions.

Comment: Hey, I'm new to all this, so it would take me some time for all this to make sense. Here's a matlab [code for 2D](http://limitless-thoughts.blogspot.in/2011/05/hus-seven-moments-invariant-matlab-code.html) image. Can you give me some tips as to how to convert it into 3D? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use MatLab. But normally the code goes through your 2D image (computing the surface, and the centroid), so there are two loops (X and Y). In 3D, you have to ass one more loop for Z.

Comment: Moments are defined as a sum (or integral) of local  real or probability mass densities times distances from an origin. Generalization to n-dimensions is mathematically trivial.